# Does `QLPreviewItem` works with local files only?

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm uploading images to `firebase` and in return I'm getting uploaded image URL as `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mobile-ae-4a739.appspot.com/o/images%2Feecae5f7-b578-483a-a2da-b166aaf5716c?alt=media&token=b6743df5-7276-4b83-8e2d-f741f42c956e`.

Now, I have to display this image in `QLPreviewController`. I'm giving the above firebase URL of my uploaded image as `QLPreviewItem`, but `QLPreviewController` displaying filename text instead of image, you can see in the below screenshot. I confirm that the URL has image.

[image]

Can you please help me to show the images in `QLPreviewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QLPreviewItem` works with local file URLs only, it won't download your file for you if you provide it a remote file url.

You need to download your file to your app's local file system before presenting `QLPreviewController` and provide it that local file url.

For advanced usage - multiple urls, dataSource, delegate handling - you should watch [Quick Look Previews from the Ground Up](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/237/) from **WWDC 2018**.